# How to limit object creation to abstract factory class only?

Tags: c#, abstract-factory

Consider the following class structure.

```
interface IClassA
{
    void methodA();
}

interface IFactoryA
{
    IClassA CreateClassA();
}
class ClassA : IClassA
{
    public void methodA() { }
}

class FactoryA : IFactoryA
{
    public IClassA CreateClassA()
    {
        return new ClassA();
    }
}
```

I want to restrict the creation of new ClassA objects only to the FactoryA class. if an attempt is made to directly create a new ClassA object using the new keyword, this should give an error.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        IFactoryA factory = new FactoryA();
        IClassA classA = factory.CreateClassA();

        //I want to restrict being able to instantiate the class directly as below
        IClassA newClassA = new ClassA();


    }
}
```

How can this be achieved? I tried to use a modified singleton object with a private constructor and a public getInstance method but is not what I want because a client code can still call the getInstance method directly.

Comment: This is a nice first question.

Comment: Make `ClassA` a private nested class within `FactoryA`.

Comment: @Lee won't that mean that nothing outside `FactoryA` will be able to see it at all?

Comment: @ChrisF - Yes but it looks like it should only be accessed through the `IClass1` interface.

Comment: @Lee, the `ClassA` should be accessed outside of the `FactoryA` both at the server and client (mobile app). I guess @HimBromBeere suggestion might work, make the constructor internal and put in the same assembly as the factory and then define DTOs at the client side. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Hiding the constructor of a class to the outside is the core-point of a factory-class:

```
interface IClassA
{
    void methodA();
}

interface IFactoryA
{
    IClassA CreateClassA();
}
class ClassA : IClassA
{
    internal ClassA() {}
    public void methodA() { }
}

class FactoryA : IFactoryA
{
    public IClassA CreateClassA()
    {
        return new ClassA();
    }
}
```

Now only the assembly where `ClassA` is defined can create instances of the class. This assumes that the factory *is* in the same assembly.

However there is no way to restrict access to a method to only one single class or method.

As Lee pointed out you can also nest the class into the factory:

```
class FactoryA : IFactoryA
{
    public IClassA CreateClassA()
    {
        return new ClassA();
    }

    class ClassA : IClassA
    {
        public void methodA() { }
    }   
}
```

Comment: thanks, this should work for me. The factory and class definitions can be a server-side assembly while the `ClassA` can be mapped to a DTO for manipulation at the client side.